# Adding composite foreign key fails in MySQL5

Tags: mysql, foreign-key-relationship, composite-key, mysql5

I am trying to enforce that the state/province and country names in the address information for users comes from a set of tables where I list countries and state/provinces.  In order to do this I tried running an alter table command like this...

```
ALTER TABLE User
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (stateProvince,country)
    REFERENCES `StateProvince`(`name`,`countryName`);
```

Then I get this message...

> Create table 'realtorprint_dev/#sql-d5c_3d' with foreign key
>   constraint failed. There is no index in the referenced table where the
>   referenced columns appear as the first columns.

Does anybody have an idea how to handle this error message?

Here is the create for the state and country tables...

```
CREATE TABLE Country (
  name varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE StateProvince (
  countryName varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  abbreviation varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (countryName,name)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

alter table StateProvince
add constraint FK_StateProvince_Country
foreign key (countryName)
references Country (name);
```

And now for the user table...

```
create table realtorprint_dev.user (
  id bigint not null,
  created datetime,
  email varchar(255) not null,
  fax varchar(255),
  mobile varchar(255),
  name varchar(255),
  password varchar(255),
  phone varchar(255),
  title varchar(255),
  tollFree varchar(255),
  updated datetime,
  web varchar(255),
  brokerage_id bigint,
  address varchar(255),
  city varchar(255),
  country varchar(255),
  stateProvince varchar(255),
  type varchar(255),
  zipPostal varchar(255),
  activated bit not null,
  locked bit not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key FK285FEB6722226 (brokerage_id) references brokerage(id)
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There is no index in the referenced table where the referenced columns appear as the first columns.

You need an index on **StateProvince.(name,countryName)**, but you have an index on **StateProvince.(countryName,name)**.  Try reversing the order of your index, or of your FK reference.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't show the create statement i'm not sure, but I beleve this has to do with the `realtorprint_dev` table not having a primairy key.